# Three.js : Create an object on a surface and align it along the normal of this surface

Tags: three.js, alignment, normals

I want to place arrows on an object when I click on it.

A JsFiddle is better than a long explanation :

https://jsfiddle.net/p820c246/4/

My source : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1486

It works well on the upper part of the surface but it bugs on lower part, I don't understand why. It seems that it bugs when the angle of the normal is to low. If you try whith a sphere like this it works well :

```
new T.SphereGeometry(1, 3, 2)
```

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log the length of your axis `axis.length()` you will notice that it decreases as you increase the angle from `up`. It's still close to 1 on the 3rd row from the bottom, but is something like 0.7 on the second.

Change

```
var axis = new T.Vector3().crossVectors(up, normal)
.normalize(); //add this
```

and it will work

To be on the safe side, you could always normalize these axis, normals etc after a transformation and then optimize. Cross product's magnitude depends on the angle, and you used it further in operations that expect it to be unit length.

Comment: Thank you Pailhead, it's exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

That function `orientAlongNormal` does wayy too many math things. If I replace it with this:

```
function orientAlongNormal(object, coords, normal, scalar) {

  var up = new T.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
  object.up = up;//Z axis up

  //create a point to lookAt
  var newPoint = new THREE.Vector3(
      coords.x + normal.x,
      coords.y + normal.y,
      coords.z + normal.z
  );

  //aim object in direction of vector "normal" using lookAt
  object.lookAt(newPoint ); 

  //in this case the cone model is a bit wrong so we have to rotate it by 90 degrees
    object.rotateX( 0.5*Math.PI );

  //put object to coords
    object.position.addVectors(coords, normal.clone().multiplyScalar(scalar));
}
```

It works: https://jsfiddle.net/hanalulu/j9Lgeys7/

This thread helped me along the way: [Issue aligning faces in Three.JS from two seperate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162422/issue-aligning-faces-in-three-js-from-two-seperate-objects)

But the key takeaway for you is not to do complicated vector math stuff yourself and instead look for methods in the 3d engine that do it for you :)

Comment: crossVectors, setFromRotationMatrix are all the methods of the 3d engine :)

Comment: did you just downvote my working answer over semantics? im not a native english speaker and i rewrote the code to be KISS which is waht i was tryign to say

Comment: No not at all. I wanted to cancel the downvote, but i mainly did it because you changed too much of his code. If the example is using a cross product to obtain a direction, and if that direction is used for rotation, i think the issue with the math (normalization) should be fixed,not changing the entire approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's better but not totally satisfying. It worls well on a regular sphere but look at this :

https://jsfiddle.net/j9Lgeys7/2/

But it could be a great hack in some cases.

Comment: I voted it back up :) I disagree with the "too much math" remark, I'd appreciate if it were edited to "here's an alternative approach"